# Resolution refutation in proportion logic with 2 clashing literals

Tags: logic

I have done process of elimination  for the resolution rule and ended up with the set.

{pq, not p, not q}.

according to my text book: Lemma : if two clauses clash on more than one literal their resolvent is a trivial cause ... then goes on to say it is not strictly incorrect to perform resolution on such clauses but since trivial clauses contribute nothing to the satisfiability or unsatisfiability of a set of clauses we agree to delete them...

But elsewhere I Have read not to remove them since there is no reason that both of those clauses could be true.

So would the able clauses leave me with the empty set {} making my final answer that the set is unsatisfiable? Or do I leave that as my final answer? The problem said Prove that it IS satisfiable, so I'm guessing I should leave the clauses in the set so that it is, but the textbook says to remove them.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, there aren't any two clauses that would clash in two literals. Two such clauses could be {p,r,q} and {~p,~r,s} and you would get {r,~r,q,s} which is always satisfiable (tautology). So, you would remove it us useless.

In your example, you will end up with an empty set after applying two resolution steps to three clauses: {pq}, ~p yields q and {q}, {~q} yields an empty set. So, the set of clauses is not satisfiable.

If the task was to prove something is satisfiable, there must be something wrong earlier in the derivation.